# Legacy H.264 without Makefile

Tags: makefile, legacy, h.264

I received a legacy code. Its a parser of H.264. I'm trying to set up the environment to use it, but its hard.

I receive specially this errors:

`[  2%] Generating moc_h.cxx
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token`('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `/usr/bin/moc-qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtScriptTools -I/usr/include/qt4/QtXmlPatterns -I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit -I/usr/include/qt4/QtHelp -I/usr/include/qt4/QtAssistant -I/usr/include/qt4/QtDBus -I/usr/include/qt4/QtTest -I/usr/include/qt4/QtUiTools -I/usr/include/qt4/QtScript -I/usr/include/qt4/QtSvg -I/usr/include/qt4/QtXml -I/usr/include/qt4/QtSql -I/usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtDesigner -I/usr/include/qt4/Qt3Support -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/default -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qwt -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pedro/NetBeansProjects/_lali/OldCode_(copy)/H.264parser -o /home/pedro/NetBeansProjects/_lali/OldCode_(copy)/H.264parser/build/moc_h.cxx /home/pedro/NetBeansProjects/_lali/OldCode_(copy)/H.264parser/h.264parser.h'`

And I have no ideia to where starts... :(

Thanks in advance, if you need any extra info just let me knoW!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `syntax error near unexpected token(` gives a clue about the script is choking on a '(' character.

And you have a few of them in your file names, such as `OldCode_(copy)`, so start from there and either rename those directories or make sure whatever you're executing properly escapes filenames that the shell and other commands can interpret.